# patching the same module in two different files with the same mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) library to patch a module which is imported by two files, which define a class and its subclass. Something like:

```
# ---- file module_to_patch.py -----
def foo():
    return 1

def faa():
    return 2

# ---- file base_class.py -----
import module_to_patch

class base_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = module_to_patch.foo()

# ---- file sub_class.py -----
import module_to_patch

class sub_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(sub_class, self).__init__()
        self.y = module_to_patch.faa()
```

As far as I understand (see [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch)), in my test I should patch both `base_class.module_to_patch` and `sub_class.module_to_patch`, e.g.:

```
# file test_sub_class.py:
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch

class TestSubClass(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher_1 = patch('base_class.module_to_patch', autospec=True)
        self.mock_1 = self.patcher_1.start()
        self.patcher_2 = patch('sub_class.module_to_patch', autospec=True)
        self.mock_2 = self.patcher_2.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        patch.stopall()
```

Questions:

- Is there a simpler way achieve this functionality?
- If not - both patches patch the same entity, how can I make both patchers return the same `Mock()` object? Do I simply pass `mock_1` to `patcher_2` as the `new` object?
- Is the above the correct way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what I think you're trying to do would be to simply mock the module in your imported objects.  If you just want the module mocked for the whole test suite:

```
# file test_sub_class.py:
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import Mock

import sub_class
import base_class
MODULE_MOCK = Mock()
sub_class.module_to_patch = MODULE_MOCK
base_class.module_to_patch = MODULE_MOCK

class TestSubClass(TestCase):

    def test_sub_class_init(self):
        self.base_class = base_class.base_class()
        self.assertTrue(MODULE_MOCK.foo.called)

        self.sub_class = sub_class.sub_class()
        self.assertTrue(MODULE_MOCK.faa.called)
```

If you just want to mock for one test you can use [patch.object](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object) as a decorator and give it the Mock object (MOCK_OBJECT) that you want patch.object to use:

```
# file test_sub_class.py:
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import Mock, patch

import sub_class
import base_class

MOCK_OBJECT = Mock()

class TestSubClass(TestCase):

    @patch.object(sub_class, 'module_to_patch', MOCK_OBJECT)
    @patch.object(base_class, 'module_to_patch', MOCK_OBJECT)
    def test_sub_class_init(self):
        self.base_class = base_class.base_class()
        self.assertTrue(MOCK_OBJECT.foo.called)
        self.sub_class = sub_class.sub_class()
        self.assertTrue(MOCK_OBJECT.faa.called)
```

Comment: `sub_class.module_to_patch = MODULE_MOCK` will break the patched module everywhere else!

Comment: @TomSwirly That is exactly what patched is supposed to do, replace the module everywhere for the duration of the test. If you are doing something that 'breaks' because of the patching, then you are doing too much in the test and should split the test up into smaller test functions.